# Dynamically changing variable in XPath within Application Modeller

Tags: blueprism

Question:
I am working with the Application Modeller and need to use a variable in my XPath expression. Currently, I have the following XPath:

xpath
Copy code
//*[@id="detailIndex1"]/summary/div/div/div[2]
I want to make the detailIndex part dynamic so that I can use detailIndex2, detailIndex3, and so on. Essentially, I want to iterate over different indices. How can I achieve this in the Application Modeller?

I appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you!
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO5LH.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you make the match type 'dynamic' you can supply the entire text on the fly at run time via whatever stage you use.

[bpdocs app modeller documentation](https://bpdocs.blueprism.com/bp-7-3/en-us/frmIntegrationAssistant.htm)

on the docs for app modeller you can see dynamic points listed but basically you can construct/manipulate a text on the fly and then supply it at run time so you can look for the one you want. When an element is dynamic you can supply the values here:

[image: where to find dynamic entry points]

the params function will become interactable when you have dynamic match type turned on. this is wher eyou will supply values at run time.